# Entity Framework and Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I have a Visual Studio 2010 solution with an Entity Framework Data project and a MVC web site. The website works fine in the IDE when debugging, but when deployed to its own site in IIS (Even my local instance of IIS) it fails at any view hitting the provider. `CNR.HARPS.DATA` is the data project with the .edmx file. I just cannot see why it works in the IDE but not when running in IIS iteself.

```
[ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.]
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetFactory(String providerString) +251

[ArgumentException: The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid.]
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetFactory(String providerString) +10983191
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String newConnectionString) +641
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(String connectionString, String defaultContainerName) +84
   CNR.HARPS.ENTITIES.HARPSDataModel..ctor() in D:\GAP.CONVERSION\CNR.HARPS\Dev\CNR.HARPS\CNR.HARPS.DATA\HARPS.Context.cs:23
   CNR.HARPS.DATA.FeeOwnerRepository..ctor() in D:\GAP.CONVERSION\CNR.HARPS\Dev\CNR.HARPS\CNR.HARPS.DATA\Repositories\FeeOwnerRepository.cs:22
   CNR.HARPS.WEB.CONTROLLERS.FeeOwnerController..ctor() in D:\GAP.CONVERSION\CNR.HARPS\Dev\CNR.HARPS\CNR.HARPS.WEB\Controllers\FeeOwnerController.cs:31

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +117
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +247
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +106
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +84
```

Comment: What provider are you using? SQLCE?

Comment: Are you using SQLite? In that case you may be missing a reference to the database provider factory.

Comment: post the connection string please

Comment: Here is the connection string: <add name="HARPSDataModel" connectionString="metadata=res://*/HARPS.csdl|res://*/HARPS.ssdl|res://*/HARPS.msl;provider=Oracle.DataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=GAPDEV;PASSWORD=htc_iltb_0805;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=HTCROYALTY&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /> This string works fine, that app works fine, when running in the cassini web server but not IIS 7.

Answer (score 3):

I found the issue.  In the IIS 7 application pool, I had to set Enable 32-Bit Applications to true.